# Webpack bundle repository not found

Tags: symfony, webpack, composer-php, symfony-3.3

I have in my `composer.json` :

```
"symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "*",
```

In composer.lock :

```
{
        "name": "symfony/webpack-encore-pack",
        "version": "v1.0.3",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore-pack.git",
            "reference": "8d7f51379d7ae17aea7cf501d910a11896895ac4"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/webpack-encore-pack/zipball/8d7f51379d7ae17aea7cf501d910a11896895ac4",
            "reference": "8d7f51379d7ae17aea7cf501d910a11896895ac4",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "symfony/asset": "^3.3|^4.0"
        },
        "type": "symfony-pack",
        "extra": {
            "thanks": {
                "name": "symfony/webpack-encore",
                "url": "https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore"
            }
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "MIT"
        ],
        "description": "A pack for Symfony Encore",
        "abandoned": "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle",
        "time": "2018-07-16T10:15:28+00:00"
    },
```

When I try composer install I have the error : `Installing symfony/webpack-encore-pack (v1.0.3): Downloading    Failed to download symfony/webpack-encore-pack from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/webpack-encore-pack/zipball/8d7f51379d7ae17aea7cf501d910a11896895ac4" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)`.

I checked this URL and the file didn't exist. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: While I agree with the answer's analysis, I still find it to be a bit strange that the package cannot be installed using composer.lock.  Always thought released packages hung around forever.  Does your composer.json file have a relevant repository section?

Comment: @Cerad I would assume that a package that is deleted completely from Github is deleted completely from Github, which would also mean that any zipped versions of that package are gone

Comment: @Cerad just the line that I wrote related to webpack.

Comment: @NicoHaase  Most released packages end up on the packagist site.  What happens on github is irrelevant.  But in this case the package seems to have been published to api.github.com/repos.  Which just seems a bit strange.  I asked about the repository section because I thought maybe it was being loaded directly from a github repo.  But that does not seem to be the case.  Just strange to me to see a published public package completely disappear.

Comment: @Cerad Package **metadata** appear on Packagist, while the sourcecode itself is not mirrored there. I've just had a look at two projects (one with pretty old dependencies, one with current ones), and they always point to `https://api.github.com/repos` for their source code - or did you encounter anything different?

Comment: @NicoHaase I agree that api.github is used for storing the zipballs.  I just don't understand what could have caused the removal of a particular file.  Even for an abandoned package.  I always trusted composer.lock to load things even if they were old. Oh well.  Lots of things I don't understand.

Comment: @Cerad What happens in Github is **very** relevant. The actual releases are not hosted on packagist, or on any other **composer** repository. The composer repository hosts, as Nico says, only the metadata. It's a search registry to know where to fetch the actual code (Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket). And in any case, when using `composer install` packagist is not contacted at all.  composer just reads `composer.lock` to know where to download the files. If the files themselves do not exist (vcs repo archived, deleted, etc)... 404.

Comment: This is a very real issue about reproducibility for old applications. The `lock` can only be trusted as much as the actual VCS repository exists. For most open source code, it's at most archived. But outright deletions and renames have actually happened. It's a bit of an achilles heel for the whole "install from your lock file idea". With containerarization, you can at least create a runnable build that contains all the code for a given deployment, and store that in a private container registry.

Comment: @yivi Guess I have just been lucky not to have encountered this before.  Chalk up another reason to avoid third party bundles.

Comment: @Cerad, I wouldn't have considered symfony/webpack-encore-pack a third-party bundle. I'm quite surprised they completely deleted it.

Answer (score 3):

`symfony/webpack-encore-pack` has seen its last update more than three years ago and is abandoned. The code is no longer present on Github, so it cannot be downloaded from the location that is stored in your `composer.lock` (that's what `https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/webpack-encore-pack/zipball/8d7f51379d7ae17aea7cf501d910a11896895ac4` does: it links to the URL of a zipped version of that package in a specific version).

According to [a discussion about this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/42700), you should use `symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` instead. Sadly, this package is not compatible with Symfony 3.3 in any version, so you might need to update it to v3.4

Comment: so in this case I should delete from composer.json : `"symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "*"` and remove from composer.lock all regarding `webpack-encore-pack`, and install `webpack-encore-bundle`