# How can I upgrade Webpack Encore bundle?

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I have a Symfony 4.4 project and I need to upgrade from `symfony/webpack-encore-pack` to `symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`. I want to do it in the best way, so can you tell me what's the best practice to do this operation (to take care of possibile dependencies and so on)?

Comment: The news is not good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014701/webpack-bundle-repository-not-found#comment121983476_69014701

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack bundle repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014701/webpack-bundle-repository-not-found)

Comment: If that does not help, please share what you've tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 3):

1. Temporarily rename your existing `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.bak.js` to allow Symfony Flex to copy a fresh config there.
2. Replace `symfony/webpack-encore-pack` dependency with `symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` in your `composer.json`
3. Run `composer update` - it should replace the old package with the new one and Symfony Flex will copy default configuration from the recipe: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/tree/master/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle/1.9
4. Upgrade your `yarn`/`npm` dependencies using `yarn upgrade @symfony/webpack-encore` or `npm upgrade @symfony/webpack-encore`.
5. Update your new `webpack.config.js` with JS/CSS entries from the back up file. Please note that syntax and option names might have changed - check [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md).
6. Run `npm run dev` to see if your assets are still building properly.